# Get count of nodes containing in taxonmoy using drupal search after entering search keyword

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-8

I have built custom search using Search API and view in drupal 8.

I have got count of nodes beside every taxonmony. What I want to achieve is I want to get count after user search anything so If user search 'test page', it should get count of all pages under the taxonomy term.

I have added image for more reference.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApxWP.png)

Comment: Hey ! I recommend you to start searching & digging about "Facets" using the Search API or the Facets module (https://www.drupal.org/project/facets). These articles may also help you https://medium.com/@swappyp20/creating-a-faceted-search-view-in-drupal-8-using-the-search-api-modules-2b2604ad37f4 & https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-implement-faceted-search-solr-drupal-8

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. but this is not I am looking for it contains number of nodes before search happens